# how to use intel tbb concurrent unordered map

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

Following is the code that I used to start learn as how to use the `concurrent` container from `Intel TBB`.

The code just tries to populate the `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map`.

I have installed `Intel TBB` on by Ubuntu using the following command:
`sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev`

However, when I compile the code as : `g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp -ltbb concur_hash.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <omp.h>

#include "tbb/concurrent_unordered_map.h"

int main() {
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<int, int> ht;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
    vec.push_back({1,1});
    vec.push_back({1,9});
    vec.push_back({2,1});
    vec.push_back({2,2});
    vec.push_back({2,7});
    vec.push_back({3,0});
    vec.push_back({3,0});
    vec.push_back({3,0});
    vec.push_back({3,0});
    vec.push_back({3,10});

    const int vec_size = vec.size();


    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; ++i) {
        auto it = ht.find(vec[i].first); 
        if (it != ht.end()) {
            it->second += vec[i].second;
        }   
        else { ht.insert(vec[i]); }
    }

    for (auto kv : ht) {
        std::cout << "k: " << kv.first << "\t v: " << kv.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

It throws the following error, which I am not able to comprehend.

```
`/tmp/cckL17EZ.o: In function `tbb::tbb_allocator<tbb::interface5::internal::flist_iterator<tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >, std::pair<int const, int> > >::deallocate(tbb::interface5::internal::flist_iterator<tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >, std::pair<int const, int> >*, unsigned long)':
concur_hash.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal14flist_iteratorINS2_18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS7_EEEES7_EEE10deallocateEPSA_m[_ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal14flist_iteratorINS2_18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS7_EEEES7_EEE10deallocateEPSA_m]+0x1c): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
/tmp/cckL17EZ.o: In function `tbb::tbb_allocator<tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::node>::deallocate(tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::node*, unsigned long)':
concur_hash.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS6_EEE4nodeEE10deallocateEPS9_m[_ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS6_EEE4nodeEE10deallocateEPS9_m]+0x1c): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
/tmp/cckL17EZ.o: In function `tbb::tbb_allocator<tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::node>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
concur_hash.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS6_EEE4nodeEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS6_EEE4nodeEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x29): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_via_handler_v3(unsigned long)'
/tmp/cckL17EZ.o: In function `tbb::tbb_allocator<tbb::interface5::internal::flist_iterator<tbb::interface5::internal::split_ordered_list<std::pair<int const, int>, tbb::tbb_allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >, std::pair<int const, int> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
concur_hash.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal14flist_iteratorINS2_18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS7_EEEES7_EEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN3tbb13tbb_allocatorINS_10interface58internal14flist_iteratorINS2_18split_ordered_listISt4pairIKiiENS0_IS7_EEEES7_EEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x20): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_via_handler_v3(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

Comment: That's not the error, it's just part of the backtrace. Anyway, linker arguments go to the back; I'll look for a dupe.

Comment: @BaummitAugen got it. it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try `g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp concur_hash.cpp -ltbb`

Comment: yup, that worked!